# How to get JS variables to be used in python file

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, geolocation

Good day everyone. I need help with trying to obtain variables from JS to be used in my python code. I've looked all over google, and tried using AJAX and JQuery without any luck. I'm probably just not doing it right.

My goal is to be able to use HTML5 Geolocation for accuracy and use the coordinates in my python code. If anyone could help me out that would be awesome. Thanks.

> Python Code

```
from flask import *
from flask_jsglue import JSGlue
app = Flask(__name__)
jsglue = JSGlue(app)
import json

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('the_new_html.html')

@app.route('/receiver', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def worker():
    lat = request.form['lat']
    long = request.form['long']
    print(lat)
    print(long)






if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> HTML file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geo</title>
    <script>
      window.onload = function()
      {

        init();
      }

      function init()
      {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionsuccess,
        positionerror);
      }

      function positionsuccess(position)
      {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = lat;
        document.getElementById('long').innerHTML = long;
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      function positionerror(error)
      {
        alert(error.message);
      }


    </script>
    <script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      Lat: <span id='lat'></span>
      Long: <span id='long'></span>
      <button type="submit" name="button">Button</button>
    </form>
    <script>

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put in the code you tried to make the AJAX call with and we can help fix it.  Also, you've got an opening `<script>` tag in there (before the jQuery include) and that will definitely cause issues.

Comment: $.ajax({
   url: '/receiver',
   data: cord,
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
   },
   error: function(error){
    console.log(error);
   }

Comment: Please post it in the question, and read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Geo</title>
        <script>
          window.onload = function()
          {

            init();
          }

          function init()
          {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionsuccess,
            positionerror);
          }

          function positionsuccess(position)
          {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = lat;
            document.getElementById('long').innerHTML = long;
            event.preventDefault();
          }
          function positionerror(error)
          {
            alert(error.message);
          }

          function buttonClickHandler() {
            const lat = document.getElementById('lat').textContent;
            const long = document.getElementById('long').textContent;
            fetch('/receiver', , {
               method: 'post',
               headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
               },
              body: JSON.stringify({lat, long})
               }).then(res=>res.json())
              .then(res => console.log(res));
          }

        </script>
        <script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form>
          Lat: <span id='lat'></span>
          Long: <span id='long'></span>
          <button type="button" name="button" onclick="buttonClickHandler">Button</button>
        </form>
        <script>

        </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

On your Flask Server you get the data here:

```
@app.route('/receiver', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def worker():
    data= request.data
    print(data)
```

Comment: I think thats what i tried here but still got nothing. Can you give an example by chance?

Comment: your form has no input fields. Sure that your post have any data? You can check it in the Developer Tools, Network. And your input fields does need names.

Comment: Check the fundamentales. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Your form have no action and no fields. So your sending form have no data.

Comment: this is  just a rough draft of my actual flask code. On my app i have a button that marks the person en route and marks a timestamp, but i want to use that button to send their geolocation to the server at the same time.

Comment: I dont know how to do that haha. Thats what im trying to figure  out

Comment: You can use the Fetch API. 
Example:
const payload = { x: 200, y: 100};

var data = new FormData();
data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );

fetch("/target/json/",
{
    method: "POST",
    body: data
})

It would work without the new Formdata too. You only need to stringify your object: JSON.stringify({x: 200, y:100'})

Comment: do i do this in my html file in the script?

Comment: That is Javascript. You can use fetch in your button-handler. It's JavaScript. One Question: are you new to HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: never messed with javascript until lastnight. Been using html/css/flask for about a month.

Comment: ah okay. one moment i will write an example

Comment: thank you. im trying to simply get the coordinates from HTML5 Geolocation and send the results to my flask/python.

Comment: ok i read your edit. thanks by the way. Now in my python file, do i just do a post request ie. lat = request.POST['lat']? to get the value?

Comment: A post request is from Client to Server. Not from Server to Client.

Comment: ok i did everything that you did and still not getting results.

Comment: Ok i stop here now. I think you must learn to much fundamentals that i can't teach you in this night. Sorry dude. If you don't can said what doesn't work, i can't help you. 
Do you send a request?
Got the server the request?

Comment: i dont get any error. just not showing up in my console when i print it

Comment: make a console.log in your buttonHandler.... was it called? make print in your receiver. was it called after you hitting the button?

Comment: no nothing was called. Did you by chance look at my dpaste code?

Comment: i see the coordinates in the console on chrome, but how do i get the data

Comment: nice. Can you post your Solution too?